# React Native - override headerStyle inside TabNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to override a StackNavigator headerStyle.

My navigation structure: a root StackNavigator with a TabNavigator (with some screens inside), and another screen.

```
 const AppStack = StackNavigator(
  {
    Tabs: AppTabNavigator, 
    Messages: MessagesScreen 
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) =>({
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: PRIMARY_COLOR,
        height: 50
      }
    })
  }
);
```

One of my Tab screens, the ProfileScreen is where i need to override some headerStyle properties like height and color, so i tried this:

```
export default class ProfileScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
      title: 'Chat',
      headerStyle:{ 
        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
        height: 100
      },
      headerTitleStyle:{ color: 'green'},
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>Profile</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

Here, the profileScreen title, and title color changes, but everything inside headerStyle doesnt apply.

Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: This should work. Did you try this in a new clean project?

Comment: @Stackia yes i tried, look at this (https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2580), it's a bug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out that is a known bug as you can check [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2580)